# What is a large sudden jump (or dip) and instantaneous recovery in a stock price

Tags: stocks, investing

[image]

So why did the price tank all of a sudden and then came back to normal? What does it mean?

Comment: Related: [What happened to Home Depot's Stock in 1988?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/72825/10997), which turned out to be an entire year of bad data.

Comment: What/where is the source of your screentshot?

Comment: @BruceWayne google

Comment: @yoozer8 Marked as dupe, since OP accepted a similar answer. Thanks for finding that!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It means a bad data point. Look at other quote providers and you won't see that data point.

You can also see that the "low" for the day is higher than the bad data point.

Answer (score 9):

Sharp dips like that are almost always bad data.  Most of the time that can be verified by looking at Time & Sales.